# Find the interval of convergence of the series $ \sum^{\infty}\limits_{k=0} ((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I wish to find the interval of convergence of the following series
\begin{align} \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k \end{align}

**PROOF**

Wittingly,
\begin{align} \left[(-1)^k+3\right]^k= \begin{cases} 0,&\text{if}\;j=0;\\4^j,&\text{if}\;j=2k;\\2^j,&\text{if}\;j=2k+1.\end{cases}  \end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align} \limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\left|((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k\right|}&=|x-1|\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{ 2^{2k+1}}\\&=|x-1|\limsup_{k\to\infty} 2^{(2k+1)\times \frac{1}{k}} \\&=4|x-1| \end{align}
The series converges absolutely when $\limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\left|((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k\right|}<1,$ i.e., 
\begin{align} |x-1|< \dfrac{1}{4}\iff \dfrac{3}{4}<x<\dfrac{5}{4} \end{align}

**QUESTION:**

Why must \begin{align} \limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\left|((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k\right|}= \limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\left| 2^{2k+1}(x-1)^k\right|}\end{align}
as stated in the book before me and not
\begin{align} \limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\left|((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k\right|}= \limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\left| 4^{2k}(x-1)^k\right|}\;?\end{align}

Comment: if you ask me $$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}|x-1|\sqrt[k]{4^k}=4|x-1|$$ That is, the greater subsequence is when $((-1)^k+3)^k=4^k$. I dont see exactly where comes $2^{2k+1}$

Comment: @Masacroso: Oh oh, that has been my thought too!

Comment: @Did: Got your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your justification of the equality$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k}=\lvert x-1\rvert\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{ 2^{2k+1}}$$doesn't hold. You have $\bigl((-1)^{2k+1}+3\bigr)^{2k+1}=2^{2k+1}$. Therefore, what you should consider here is$$\sqrt[2k+1]{2^{2k+1}}=2.$$But, since $\bigl((-1)^{2k}+3\bigr)^{2k}=4^{2k}$ and$$\sqrt[2k]{4^{2k}}=4,$$you have$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k}=4\lvert x-1\rvert.$$

Comment: Sorry, I edited my work. That equation truly, does not hold!

Comment: So that, actually, he equality $$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k}=\lvert x-1\rvert\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{ 2^{2k+1}}$$ **does** hold, as you show, since $$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{ 2^{2k+1}}=4$$

Comment: But the power of $(x-1)$ is $k$. How come? From the above, we should have $ \limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\left|((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k\right|}=4^2|x-1|$ ?

Comment: @Did: Sorry, I don't get who you're referring to!

Comment: @Mike The OP starts with the assertion that A=B does not hold, then goes on to show that A=C. It happens that, obviously, C=B. Ergo, problem.

Comment: @Did: That's true! However, lets wait for him to respond.

Comment: Aaaaah... much better now. :-)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Your equality holds, but the justification was not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$
\sum^{n}_{k=0} ((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k =\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n 4^{2k}(x-1)^{2k}+2(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{2k}(x-1)^{2k}\right)
$$

and now

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n 4^{2k}(x-1)^{2k} = \frac{1-4^{2(n+1)}(x-1)^{2(n+1)} }{1-4^{2}(x-1)^{2}}
$$

which converges if $|4(x-1)| < 1$ etc. so the result is

$$
\sum^{n}_{k=0} ((-1)^k+3)^k(x-1)^k=\frac{2(x-1)}{1-2^2 (x-1)^2}+\frac{1}{1-4^2 (x-1)^2} 
$$

for $\frac 34\lt x\lt \frac 54$

Attached the plot showing in red the sum approximation for $n = 10$ and in black the asymptotic result found

[image]